# please tell me what should i do when i have many information source.( i need a architect's approach)

Tags: architecture

i am developing a website which will show details of different institutions/college.
i have got many information source for my website, means i will collect information from 4-5 webservices/websites as xml files in which their will be name, address, user rating, and detais. please tell me how to manage "DETAIL" field. as i have 4-5 sources and may be i will get different details for same institute so whose detail i should show? how to select this.

please help me and give me some good approach that how and what to do in such situation

Comment: Inappropriate calls to close are inappropriate

Comment: Hi Dot Net Developer

Can you please give some more specifics, and explain in more detail what you need to do, I am having difficulty giving advice as the goal is unclear to me.

Comment: Indeed, more information required.  This sounds like a requirements issue rather than a technical one at the moment.

Comment: i am creating a website which will show details of different institutes. i will get that details (of institutions) from different webservices through xml. so please tell me how to manage it.. i mean i can show name, address and course prices but how to manage "Details about institute" which i am getting from many sources so how to select which details should i show (about institute).

Comment: So now we close a question if we can't immediately figure out the answer?

Comment: no.. please dont close this question.. its very essential for me to get adopt a best apporach for this...

Comment: Voted to reopen, but Dot Net Developer, you really need to find a way to make your question clearer so we can answer it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they mean the same thing, treat them as the same.  If they mean different things, you'll have to decide whether to split your details into two or more information types and, depending on what webservice you're calling, use the appropriate one.

Comment: some times its also quite possible that a detail(of any institute) can come from 3 source and some time a other details come from 5 different sources..so i m thinking to create priority for that so i will show that data of that webservice whose priority is seted high.  what do  u say?

Comment: That certainly would be an option.  Also, you could append each detail to the current list and show them all, perhaps in order of importance.  You could also hide the lesser important details in the UI unless the user elects to view the additional details.

Comment: this is very good approach... but i think, i will get detail about institution for different sources will be very near to similar so i think i should not show details of all providers because that will repeat the matter... what do u say?

Comment: Without seeing them its hard to say.  If you do not have enough information to decide, provide all the information you have to users and let them determine what they wish to know.